# javascript remove required attribute is working in mixed way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have strange problem, I am submitting a registration form and have a check box script that checks if a check box is clicked to remove the requred attributes on the rest of the check boxes.

this is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".aboveage5").click(function(){
        if ($('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:checked').val() != "" ) {
            $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:not(:checked)').removeAttr('required');
             //Slide Down Effect  
        } else {           
            $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:checked').prop('required',true);    //Slide Up Effect
        }
     });            
});
```

my form code is the following:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
<input type="checkbox" required class="aboveage5"  name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]" value="val 1"  /> PAN FRANCES<br />
<input type="checkbox" required class="aboveage5"  name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]" value="val 2"  /> PAN DULCE<br />
<input type="checkbox" required  class="aboveage5" name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]" value="val 3"  /> PAN DE VIGA <br />


 <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
```

The script behaviour is the following, if I select one of the check boxes before I hit the submit button everything is working fine. But If I submit the button without any box is selected than says that thoose fields can't be blank. Once I select one of them in the code it removes the required attribute but when I hit the submit button again nothing is happening , it shows the popup ballon which says the field is requred but it doesn't says anyting inside it and if I hit the submit button the second time it submits. Problem is I have to hit the submit button 2 times until it get's submited. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

This is the validation code function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Este campo no puede dejarse en blanco");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```

**The problem seems to be inside the custom validation, since without it it works fine.**

**Problem solved with clearing the POST Array before the validation.**

Comment: just take of the required attrib from on of the inputs, and add the checked attrib instead. if they don't like it, they will change it, and everything will work fine.

Comment: can you give code answer of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".aboveage5").click(function(){
        var checkedArray =$('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:checked');
        // Check if atleast one element is checked
        if(checkedArray!=null && checkedArray.length>0){
           $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:not(:checked)').removeAttr('required');
        }else{
           $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]').attr('required',true); // Could also use .prop() instead
        }    

     });            
});
```

Comment: Stll the same thing nothing is changing.

Comment: what behavior are you experiencing with the above code? Note that I've removed :checked from the statement in else

Comment: It selects the fitst element, and gives the empty popup box without text.

Comment: I expect in case If I forgot to check something it will notify that this should be checked, after I check it , than hit the submit button to submit it. RIght now if I select it from the begining without selecting anything it works but If I forgot the select check box it gives me the remid and than I hit submit it gives me the empty popup box on the first input element. If I hit second time submit it sumits. I want to submit from the first time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.removeAttr('required')
```

try

```
.prop('required', false)
```

Comment: with .prop('required', false) - it is not doing anything everything stays requred all the time. It doesn't making anything.